# Could not launch console app with xCode 4.4

Tags: xcode

I have a project with two targets -- an iOS app and an OSX console app.  The latter was created using Xcode File->New Target and selecting "Command Line Tool".  This console app is used to prep a default database needed by the iOS app -- using CoreData.   This has been working fine until I upgraded to Mountain Lion and xCode 4.4.  Now when I try to run the command line tool I get a "Could Not Launch -- permission denied" error.  I have tried playing around with signing certificates, to no avail.  Interestingly if I create a new "hello, world" command line tool in a new project it works just fine -- and it is not signed at all.

I checked the file and it has -rwxr-xr-x permission.  In the debugger the app fails on startup even before it tries to access the moms.  If I try to run this outside of the debugger at the command line, it ends with a kill 9 message.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am having this problem; tried all the solutions below and none worked.

Answer (score 6):

I just had the same problem in my iOS/Mac project. None of the above suggestions helped but I managed to find the correct answer so I'm sharing for future ref.

I had to set code signing to **Don't codesign** for the MacOSX target. The rest works fine no matter if your deployment target is set to default or not. Don't forget to set your Base SDK to **Current OSX** and supported platforms to **"x86_64 i386"**.

HTH! Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Also you can get "Could Not Launch -- permission denied" error when trying to launch app on device with password which not unlocked at launch time.

Comment: For me, this is the what exactly happened.

Comment: Me too! I hope it's written somewhere in the docs and it's just me that didn't find it, otherwise it's a colossal fail in communication! I wasted half an hour looking through certificates and profiles before finding this answer

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer.  On the Info page I had to change OS X deployment target from Default to 10.8.  Default I guess no longer defaults correctly.  Anyway it now works.

Answer (score 1):

I also saw this error message when attempting to run a newly created Cocoa app target. The problem was that I had created my app target in an iOS app project, but instead I needed to create a subproject and create the app target in the new project.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this when I tried to run before creating and installing the provisioning profile.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I changed deployment target to 10.8(previous is 10.6),and it works.